# When I use the generic method in Route then I am getting compiler Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, generics, ktor

I am trying to create a dynamic service based on the data class model defined by user and they registerDataModels() method appDataModule() it should automatically create all based method in the router service. When I try to achive using generics in those method I am getting a compiler error. Is there any other better way to dynamically create route methods like by defining the datamodel by developer and then service should be automatically created?

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during IR lowering
File being compiled: */api/AppConfigService.kt
The root cause java.lang.RuntimeException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.codegen.FunctionCodegen.generate(FunctionCodegen.kt:47)

File is unknown
The root cause java.lang.AssertionError was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.coroutines.CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.spillVariables(CoroutineTransformerMethodVisitor.kt:636)


fun Application.registerDataModels() {
  appDataModule<M1>()
  appDataModule<M2>()
  appDataModule<M3>()
}

inline fun <reified T: DBModel> Application.appDataModule() {
  routing {
    createAppData<T>()
    updateAppData<T>()
    deleteAppData<T>()
  }
}

inline fun <reified T: DBModel> Route.createAppData() {
  put("/api/data/${getName<T>()}/create") {
    authenticated {
      create<T>{}
    }
  }
}

inline fun <reified T: DBModel> Route.updateAppData() {
  put("/api/data/${getName<T>()}/update") {
    authenticated {
      update<T>{}
    }
  }
}

inline fun <reified T: DBModel> Route.deleteAppData() {
  put("/api/data/${getName<T>()}/delete") {
    authenticated {
      delete<T>{}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: This answer assumed that code would be loaded at runtime, which seems not to be the case, and is therefore not completely matching OP's question.*

You are using `inline` functions with `reified`.

To make a long story short, `inline` functions are compiled and 'copied' to the location where they are being used, already with a fixed (thats what reified does) class. So when you use an inline function

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T> foo(t: T): T { ... }
```

and you call it like this:

```kotlin
val myVal = foo("test").uppercase()
```

then at compile time of that calling line of code, the type of T is known to be String and the target line is compiled accordingly, so you know at runtime which type T is within your function.
It is (for this one calling line) as if that function was like this to begin with:

```kotlin
fun foo(t: String): String { ... }
```

Because you want to compile these classes dynamically, however, this process fails, because the class obviously does not exist yet. This is simply due to the nature of `reified`. If you can somehow remove it, it might work.

I agree that the error message of the compiler could be more telling here. Maybe you can raise a task on kotlin's issue tracking platform?: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/kt?_gl=1*5r6x4d*_ga*MTQyMDYxMjc2MS4xNjMzMzQwMzk5*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY2OTM1NjM1MS4yMS4xLjE2NjkzNTYzNTcuMC4wLjA.&_ga=2.265829455.1332696793.1669356352-1420612761.1633340399

Comment: Thanks for helping, Other libraries like databases and different ones have only inline functions, so I couldn't able to use them without reified. I also found a complex way to solve it. I have not tried it yet. Creating Gradle Plugin - Using compile time code generator. [Reference1](https://medium.com/tompee/kotlin-annotation-processor-and-code-generation-58bd7d0d333b) [Reference2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2RoLFzrFG0)

Comment: Creating Code Generate before compilation using KotlinPoet and Annotations is working very well. Try to use the reference1 and reference2 links above.

Comment: Ah, I see. For some reason I assumed that when you spoke of dynamic service, that you meant the users/admins are able to write 'on the fly' code and load it at runtime, which would then be strictly after compilation, obviously. But if you know all sources at compilation, then obviously you can work around it.

Comment: I adapted the answer to warn about the fact that I misunderstood the scenario.

Comment: At runtime, it is better to use without reified. so only I accepted. The problem with mine is that the dependency library did not have a basic generic; instead, they went with inline reified. Rewriting the extension of dependencies would take time. So I went with compilation. Also during build time, we would know the models so we can generate service during that time itself at best.